# How to Classify into 3 Age Categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to categorize age into 3 categories:

- Below 55
- 55-64
- 65 and above

What’s an Excel formula that I can use to get this? Age is in numeric values- integers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This just requires a couple of simple IF functions.

```
=IF(A1 < 55,"GRP 1",IF(A1 < 65, "GRP 2", "GRP 3"))
```

[image]

---

> ## [IF Function <sub><sup>(support.office.com)</sup></sub>](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)
>
> *The IF function is one of the most popular functions in Excel, and it allows you to make logical comparisons between a value and what you expect.*
>
> *So an IF statement can have two results. The first result is if your comparison is True, the second if your comparison is False.*

---

This can also be done by creating a very simply UDF that utilizes a [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) statement.

```vb
Public Function AgeCategories(ByVal Age As Long) As String

    Select Case Age
    Case 0 To 54
        AgeCategories = "Group 1"
    Case 55 To 64
        AgeCategories = "Group 2"
    Case Else
        AgeCategories = "Group 3"
    End Select

End Function
```

Which your formula would look like:

```
=AgeCategories(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing and for the quick responses. Tried the If statements but they didn't work. Perhaps it's not picking up on the "between" 55 and 64 years.

On UDF Select Cases, I'm afraid my skill level has not reached the point where I can use it confidently. It's good to have it though to try it in future.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

From What you have mentioned, I think It will be a good idea to crate a drop down list. 
Refer to this tutorial to get better Understanding: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/